# Looking for a multiselectioncell in GWT

Tags: gwt, drop-down-menu, cell, uibinder

Is there something like a [SelectionCell](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/SelectionCell.html) in GWT that allows for multi-selection of the choices that appear in the drop-down menu?

I'd like to add a drop-down menu to my app that enables selecting multiple choices from the drop-down menu using SHIFT - mouse click or CONTROL - mouse click, but the standard SelectionCell from GWT does not allow that behavior.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to implement a dropdown that handles multiple selections yourself, then make a custom cell that wraps that dropdown. Or, much easier, you could use a listbox that handles multiple selections and create a custom cell to wrap around that.